# hide cell contents in excel column

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have an excel sheet where i get email addresses in column J.
The code generates excel sheets using open xml package and depending on row index and cell reference, values are imported in the sheet.
This field has to be used as a dynamic input for a button click event present on excel so not necessary to display the field.
I need to hide the email addresses and not make the whole column invisible.
Please advice.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can get better answers to your questions if you let us know [what you have tried.](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: What if you right click on the column to hide it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but might be worth a try.

http://www.ehow.com/how_2212385_hide-cell-contents-excel.html

Comment: Thnx to all! but I made complete change in the approach. Instead of assigning email address to columns in all rows on importing data, and making the whole column invisible,  I just took the email address field in a variable and assigned it to an unused cell and made the whole row invisible.